# Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function wp_redirect() in custom plugin

Tags: wordpress

I have created a plugin which have a form that i show on front using shortcode. When user submit the form the data will be inserted in the table and user will be redirected to URL(for now to home url). The data is inserting in the database but wp_redirect gives error `Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function wp_redirect()`

I even tried to redirect using javascript but still no luck.

### Here is my code:

```
if(isset($_POST['cc-user-details']))
{
global $wpdb;
$table_name=$wpdb->prefix ."opu_userdata";
$wpdb->insert($table_name,array('name'=>$_POST['cc-name'],'mobile'=>$_POST['cc-mobile'],'email'=>$_POST['cc-email'],'annual_salary'=>$_POST['cc-salary'],'product'=>'credit card'));
$_SESSION['user_cc']=$_POST['cc-name'];
$_SESSION['cc-salary']=$_POST['cc-salary'];

wp_redirect(home_url());
exit;
}
```

Comment: Where is your form submitting to? What is the `form` `action` attribute set to? WP has a built in method of handling form submissions like this using the `admin_post_nopriv_{$action}` hook: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/admin_post_nopriv_action/ -- I would suggest looking into this route as this will ensure all `wp_*` functions are loaded. You are most likely trying to run `wp_redirect()` before that function is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
$home_url=home_url();
 header('Location: {$home_url}');
```

in the place of:

```
wp_redirect(home_url());
```

Comment: its redirecting to the same page which have form. tried it by replacing home url with other domain... still redirect to the the page which have form